# Axios fetching data from different url when providing route with params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am running react app and node server on a proxy and when providing params to a route it fetches data from
**http://localhost:3000/confirmation/api/token/1** instead of **http://localhost:3000/api/token/1**
if i dont provide any parameters to Confirmation.js
Like  `<Route path="/confirmation" element={<Confirmation />} />`
the request is working fine.

App.js
`<Route path="/confirmation/:token" element={<Confirmation />} />`

Confirmation.js

```
    const { token } = useParams()
    const [details, setDetails] = useState(null)

    const fetchDetails = useCallback(async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`api/token/${token}`)
        console.log(response.data)
    }, [token])


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchDetails()
    }, [fetchDetails])
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `/` before `api/token/${token}`?

Comment: I'm sure vighnesh153 meant ```axios.get(`/api/token/${token}`)```, i.e. not a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was not a relative path , changing `api/token/${token}` to `/api/token/${token}` fixed it. Thanks to @vighnesh153

Answer (score 1):

you have to add base url for api calling:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com'; // your base url
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN; // auth if needed
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

Comment: have tried like this http://localhost:3000/api/token/${token} and add some photos for better undastand.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using the full URL on the request:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/token/${token}`)
```

Or, you can create a "helper" for axios. Something like this:

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4001'
})
```

Then you do for example:

```
api.get('/v1/users')
```

Will send a request to: http://localhost:4001/v1/users
Export this "api" from a file and import it wherever you want to use it.